# How to implement a private function that returns a protected structure

Tags: c++

So what I am trying to do is I want to have a class `LinkedList` and in the header file I have a protected struct `ListNode` that has a string value parameter and a pointer to the next node. In my public member functions I have a add function that calls a private add function that is recursive. 
Here is the H file.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define LINKEDLIST_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class LinkedList
{
protected:   // Declare a class for the list node.
struct ListNode
{
   string value;
   ListNode *next;
   ListNode(string value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
   {
      value = value1;
      next = next1;
   }
};
ListNode *head;                  // List head pointer
public:
    LinkedList() { head = NULL; }   // Constructor
    ~LinkedList();                  // Destructor
    void add(string value) { head = add(head, value);}
private:
    // Recursive implementations
    ListNode *add(ListNode *aList, string value);   //Function called by the void add function in public
};
#endif // LINKEDLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

The problem arises when I try to implement this recursive add function. I have tried the code below but I keep getting an error that *ListNode does not have a type*. Even though I have defined it as a protected attribute?

Here is the Implementation file.

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
//Destructor works fine, nothing wrong here and we are using ListNode
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{    ListNode *garbage;
    head = garbage;
    delete garbage;
}
//Error comes from this recursive add function
ListNode LinkedList::*add(ListNode *aList, string val)
{
    //add a node recursively
}
```

Any help on what I need to change is Greatly Appreciated.

(note) if you need anymore information I would gladly post it. I just want some help. Thank you!

Comment: `ListNode LinkedList::*add` -> `ListNode* LinkedList::add`

Comment: Yeah I tried what you said and it still says that ListNode does not have a type, It was a great idea but still for some reason it still doesn't have a type, or scope.

Comment: @AndyG the error is `error: ‘ListNode’ does not name a type` that's all the error says and the line number of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinkedList::ListNode* LinkedList::add(ListNode *aList, string val)
```

You need to properly scope `ListNode*` as under `LinkedList`, since it's declared within the class declaration.

Comment: Thank you this is a life saver, Best Answer!

Answer (score 1):

The type is `LinkedList::ListNode`, not `ListNode`. Using only `ListNode` inside the `LinkedList` class and its methods works, because the context is clear, but once you are outside of it you must write the full type.

This should work:

```
LinkedList::ListNode* LinkedList::add(ListNode* aList, string val)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: You also need to remove the extra * before `add`.